# Error installing SQL Server Database Engine Services with SQL Server 2019 on Windows 11 Home

Tags: sql-server, windows-11

I am facing an issue in installing SQL Server 2019 on my Windows 11 Home machine.

The problem is

> Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes

I have added the log details below

```
Detailed results:
  Feature:                       Database Engine Services
  Status:                        Failed
  Reason for failure:            An error occurred during the setup process of the feature.
  Next Step:                     Use the following information to resolve the error, uninstall this feature, and then run the setup process again.
  Component name:                SQL Server Database Engine Services Instance Features
  Component error code:          0x851A001A
  Error description:             Wait on the Database Engine recovery handle failed. Check the SQL Server error log for potential causes.
  Error help link:               https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkId=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=50000&ProdVer=15.0.4013.40&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026&EvtType=0xD15B4EB2%400x4BDAF9BA%401306%4026
```

I tried reinstalling the SQL Server multiple times, both Developer edition and Express edition, but no luck.

I also tried changing the `NT Service/MSSQLServer` to `NTAuthority/NetworkService` or `NTAuthority/LocalSystem`, but again - no luck.

Could anyone help me?

[image]

Event Viewer log:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The installation storage device seems to have/report an inappropriate sector size.

Take a look at [Troubleshoot errors related to system disk sector size greater than 4 KB](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/admin/troubleshoot-os-4kb-disk-sector-size) and [Microsoft support policy for 4K sector hard drives in Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/backup-and-storage/support-policy-4k-sector-hard-drives).